# F# fails with "Error 4 This expression was expected to have type int but here has type int -> int"

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Here is the code that I am trying to get to work last line is where it is failing:

```
let rec gcd a b =
    if b= 0 then
        a
    else
        gcd b (a % b);;

let n = 8051
let mutable d = 0
let mutable c = 1
let mutable xi = 2
let mutable yi = 2
let f x = (pown x 2) + (c % n);;
while c < 100 do
    while d = 1 do
        xi <- (f xi)
        yi <- (f(f(yi)))
        printfn "%d%d" xi yi        
        d <- gcd(abs (xi - yi) n)
```

---------------------The Following Code works; Except for integer overflow on N---------

```
module Factorization


let rec gcd a b =
    if b= 0 then
        a
    else
        gcd b (a % b);;

let n = 600851475143N
let mutable d, c, xi, yi = 1, 1, 2, 2
let f x = (pown x 2) + (c % n);;

let maxN m =int(ceil(sqrt(float m)))
//if (n > maxN(xi)) && (n >  maxN(yi)) then
while c < 100 do
    d <- 1
    while d = 1 do        
        if (maxN(n) > xi) && (maxN(n) >  yi) then
            xi <- f xi
            yi <- f(f(yi))           
            d <- gcd (abs (xi - yi)) n
            //fail
            if d = n then d<-1
            if d <> 1 then printfn "A prime factor of %d x = %d,  y = %d, d = %d" n xi yi d
        else
            xi <- 2
            yi <- 2
            c  <- c + 1;;
```

Comment: I think you are never going to execute the last line, since you are initializing d to 0 but doing a `while d = 1` :)

Comment: Interestingly, he will not execute the last line infinetly often, as c is never changed, so remains 1, which is < 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what @Rangoric pointed out, the outer brackets have to go as well otherwise currying won't work:

```
d <- gcd (abs(xi-yi)) n
```

Comment: That is what I was missing! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yikes, here are a few unsolicited tips (@BrokenGlass answered the question itself correctly).

First, you can assign all those mutables in one line:

```
let mutable d, c, xi, yi = 0, 1, 2, 2
```

Second, go easy on the parentheses:

```
xi <- f xi
yi <- f (f yi)
```

And of course, try to get rid of the mutables and while loops. But I'll leave that to you since I'm sure you are aware seeing that you implemented `gcd` using recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
d <- gcd (abs(xi-yi)) n
```

It is pointing out that abs is a int->int and not an int by itself. Wrapping it in parentheses causes the abs to be executed before gcd looks at it. This causes gcd to see the result of abs instead of abs itself.

Comment: I tried that before I posted and it didn't work :( I came to the conclusion to that it was returning a function and not a value. I have tried the following:  d <- gcd((abs (xi - yi)) n) and  d <- gcd((abs (xi - yi))() n)

Comment: removed the parens, that's what I get for not trying it first.